# How to Confirm an Alert's text in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, alert

I am trying to assert that the alert that appears when clicking a button is:

> Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution.

In Cypress, it is showing that the assertion is failing because it is not the exact string that the alert is showing. Cypress showing two stars (**) at the beginning and end of the string. This is the output that Cypress is giving me when I run the test:

> **assert expected** [Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution.] **to equal** **[Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution.]**

Tried to using a `.contains()` and `.should()` but nothing would assert that the two alerts have the same message.

My code as of now is:

```
cy.button().click();
cy.on('window:alert', (str) => {
     expect(str).to.equal('[Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution.]')
})
```

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the toolbar so you can format errors (quotes) and code properly.

Comment: The alert might just be adding two astericks to the beggining and the end. Try adding it to your assert: `'**[Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution.]**'`

Comment: So when I add the asterisks it shows: assert expected [Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution.] to equal ****Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution.****

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact error you're seeing into a code block in your question? In all likelihood there's an extra space, an invisible character, or some other subtle difference between the two strings. Maybe try copying the strings into your JavaScript console in an expression like `"[first pasted string]" == "[second pasted string]"` to see if JavaScript thinks those values are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t tried this on my own by now, just going by intuition. Could you try removing the square braces from the paramter? Like so:

```
expect(str).to.equal('Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution.')
```

Comment: When I remove the brackets the astericks are still:assert expected [Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution.] to equal ** Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution. **

Answer (score 1):

If there's some whitespace around the text, it doesn't show up in the error message.

Try it with a bit less exactness

```js
expect(str).to.contain('[Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution.]')
```

or some trimming

```js
expect(str.trim()).to.eq('[Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution.]')
```

Comment: So when I try these I get: "(uncaught exception)Assertion Error: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but error given." And this happens when I try to use .contain, and .contains. When I use trim I get, "(uncaught exception)TypeError: str.trim is not a function". Im not sure why it isn't a function.

Comment: From the error message, sounds like there's no quotes around the string, or (more likely) the `str` isn't a string as the name implies but an array of strings. Take a look at `str` in the console.

Comment: No, `window.alert` passes a string value in the `str` parameter when I try it. I can't make either of those errors occur.

Comment: So I tried:

```expect(str.toString()).to.contain("Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution.")

``` and this seems to pass the assertion, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code block seems to fix the problem, Adding `str.toString()`

```js
expect(str.toString()).to.contain("Error: There was an unexpected problem with SQL query execution.")
```

Comment: This makes no sense `str.toString()` is just the same string.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but could it be that the alert was saving as str but it was not a string for some reason, could be an array of strings or something similar.